# Cannot make a hover work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a big problem with very simple thing. I cannot change the color of the background in divs. I am using bootstrap 3.3.7. There is my code

```css
#In:hover {
    background-color: #2E2E2F;
}
#Up:hover{
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div id="Signupin" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 container-fluid" style = "height: 70px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <div class="row" style=" height: 70px;">
        <div id = "Sign" class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style = "font-size:50px;   text-align: center; height: 65px;  background-color: white;">
           <p style = "margin: 0px; padding:  0px;font-family: monospace;">Sign</p> 
        </div>
    
     <!-- I would like to change background color of these two(Up and In) when the mouse is overlayed. -->
     
        <a href="C:\FreeGuide\HTML_CSS\Sign Up\signup.html">
      
            <div id = "Up" class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="height: 70px; text-align: center; background-color: #B7B7AC ">    
     
                <p style = "font-size: 50px; color: gainsboro;font-family: monospace;">Up</p>
            </div>                      
        </a>
      
        <a>
            <div id = "In" class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style = "background-color: #0E2E2F;text-align: center; height: 70px;">
    
                <p  style = "font-size: 50px;font-family: monospace; color: gainsboro;">In</p>
    
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you tell me where is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Move inline styles to your stylesheet or use `!important` in hover styles to cancel the effect of inline styles.

Comment: Why are you mixing inline & external styling? Rohit gave you something that will work, but you need to do some housekeeping. You really shouldn't use IDs for styling, otherwise, you'll end up with specificity problems again in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Because you had use background inline, but you need to can use internal CSS for hover like given below.

See below its working now:-

```css
#In{background-color: #0E2E2F;}
#In:hover {
    background-color: #2E2E2F;
}
#Up{ background-color: #B7B7AC }
#Up:hover{
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div id="Signupin" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 container-fluid" style = "height: 70px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                   <div class="row" style=" height: 70px;">
                    <div id = "Sign" class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style = "font-size:50px;   text-align: center; height: 65px;  background-color: white;">
                       <p style = "margin: 0px; padding:  0px;font-family: monospace;">Sign</p> 
                    </div>
                    
                     <!-- I would like to change background color of these two(Up and In) when the mouse is overlayed. -->
                     
                     <a href="C:\FreeGuide\HTML_CSS\Sign Up\signup.html">
                      
                     <div id = "Up" class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="height: 70px; text-align: center;">    
                     
                     <p style = "font-size: 50px; color: gainsboro;font-family: monospace;">Up</p>
                    </div>                      
                      </a>
                      
                    <a>
                    <div id = "In" class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style = "text-align: center; height: 70px; 
                    ">
                    
                    <p  style = "font-size: 50px;font-family: monospace; color: gainsboro;">In</p>
                    
                    </div>
                       </a>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `!important` to override inline styles

```css
   #In:hover{
        background: #2E2E2F!important;
    }
   #Up:hover{
        background: aquamarine!important;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="Signupin" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 container-fluid" style = "height: 70px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                       <div class="row" style=" height: 70px;">
                        <div id = "Sign" class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style = "font-size:50px;   text-align: center; height: 65px;  background-color: white;">
                           <p style = "margin: 0px; padding:  0px;font-family: monospace;">Sign</p> 
                        </div>
                        
                         <!-- I would like to change background color of these two(Up and In) when the mouse is overlayed. -->
                         
                         <a href="C:\FreeGuide\HTML_CSS\Sign Up\signup.html">
                          
                         <div id = "Up" class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="height: 70px; text-align: center; background-color: #B7B7AC ">    
                         
                         <p style = "font-size: 50px; color: gainsboro;font-family: monospace;">Up</p>
                        </div>                      
                          </a>
                          
                        <a>
                        <div id = "In" class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style = "background-color: #0E2E2F;text-align: center; height: 70px; 
                        ">
                        
                        <p  style = "font-size: 50px;font-family: monospace; color: gainsboro;">In</p>
                        
                        </div>
                           </a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make backgrounds for paragraphs:

```
#In p:hover {
    background-color: #2E2E2F;
}
#Up p:hover{
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

And please, don't use ID for styles, they are for javascript. And restrain from using `!important` unless you have no other option.